# Cannot query over 330k records from mongodb using c++

Tags: c++, mongodb

I have a mongodb replica-set store compute status data like cpu, memory,etc. 
In my web server, I use mongodb c++ driver to query data from mongodb. When the result docs is over 330,000, mongodb driver reports field not found exception:

```
2015-01-22T16:57:59.848+0800 Assertion: 13111:field not found, expected type 7
```

But if we decrease the returned number, it works correctly. Below is my code:

```
shared_ptr<Datas> DataService::QueryByEpochMin(string const& type, uint64_t start_time, uint64_t end_time) {
  Configuration& config = MyApp::Instance().config();
  shared_ptr<MongoSession> session = MongoSessionFactory::GetSession();
  shared_ptr<Datas> datas(new Datas());
  BSONObjBuilder condition;
  BSONObjBuilder t1;
  t1.append("$gte", static_cast<long long>(start_time));
  BSONObjBuilder t2;
  t2.append("$lt", static_cast<long long>(end_time));
  condition.append("epoch_min", t1.obj());
  condition.append("epoch_min", t2.obj());

  BSONObjBuilder sortBuilder;
  sortBuilder.append("epoch_min", 1);

  Query query(condition.obj());
  Query queryWithSort(query.sort(sortBuilder.obj()));

  std::unique_ptr<DBClientCursor> cursor = session->get().query(config.mongo_db_name + "." + type + "_data", queryWithSort, 330000);
  while (cursor->more()) {
    shared_ptr<Data> data(new Data());
    BSONObj record = cursor->next();
    data->host_id = record.getField("host_id").OID();
    data->epoch = record.getField("epoch").numberLong();
    data->epoch_min = record.getField("epoch_min").numberLong();
    data->load = static_cast<float>(record.getField("load").Double());
    datas->Add(data);
  }
  return datas;
}
```

In [mongodb c++ driver doc](http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/classmongo_1_1_d_b_client_base.html#a4d3665db4b8bdbb4f0841a00eb2978c4), if I do not specify the nToReturn parameter of DBClientBase::query function, it's unlimited. So what cause this problem?

Comment: Not stomping on you but I just want you to realize that all of MongoDB server and the utilities shipped with it are built on exactly the same code implemented in the driver implementation you are using. So perhaps you might re-think your question title. Something along the lines of "my code does not work when..."

Comment: Type 7 corresponds to BSON type ObjectID. Is there an element in your data that has something other than an ObjectID in a field that is expected by the code to have an ObjectID? Perhaps the particular document that has this unexpected type is around 330,000 documents deep in the collection?

Comment: It may also be relevant what version of [MongoDB you are using](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-13616)

Comment: As @NoOutlet mentioned, can you try and batch the data using skip-take and see if you can retrieve all the data after 330,000 rows? this should help eliminate bad data issues.